# Existence of dominating measure for family of probabilities over compact set of parameters

Tags: probability-distributions

Suppose we have a family of distributions $\{P_s, s\in \mathcal{S}\}$ with corresponding probabilities $\mathbb{P}_s$, where $\mathcal{S}$ is a compact set of parameters, which can be uncountable. Are this measures always dominated by some measure?

Comment: They are dominated by counting measure and in general that is the most you can say.  But I don't think I really understand your question.  What do you mean by "distribution" here - presumably a measure, but on what set?  How exactly are $P_s$ and $\mathbb{P}_s$ related?  On what set is $\mathbb{P}_s$ a measure? And also, you say $\mathcal{S}$ is compact but you never use its topology so as it stands that assumption is irrelevant.  Did you want $s \mapsto P_s$ to be continuous in some sense?